# Import-CSV cmdlet in powershell

Tags: shell, csv, import, powershell-2.0

got a problem with my powershell script.

The Import-CSV cmdlet is not working like I want it...

What I want to do?
- Import just the single names out of one column with the header "name" to create some paths.

`name 
Jack
Thomas
John`

This is my code for this function:

`$users = Import-csv -Path "$csvpath" -Header "name"
$path = ("D:\Users\" + $users)
foreach ($user in $users) {Write-Host $path}`

But the only output I'm getting is "D:\Users\"

I'm not a pro in coding so I can't see my failure :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new update:

```
$users = Import-csv -Path "$csvpath" -Header "name"
```

changed to :

```
$users = Import-csv -Path "$csvpath"
```

You can not just get $path, because $users is not a string.

```
$path = ("D:\Users\" + $users)
```

Instead, you can do this

```
foreach ($user in $users) {$path = "d:\Users\" + $user ; Write-Host $path}
```

But I think you want this:

```
foreach ($user in $users) {$path = "d:\Users\" + $user.name ; Write-Host $path}
```

==================================================

This works well in my pc. Any further information?

[screen copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXKKI.png)

Comment: I updated the code above with "$path" but that should not change anything. I've no idea why this is not working...